# ASP.NET MVC get data from SQL Server with WCF : how to put temporary data store in controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I want to do grid, I get 1000 rows of data from SQL Server with WCF, then I put grid 10 data in view in first after use scroll and get 10-20 data from controller in two after use scroll and get 20-30 data from controller in three..... use scroll and get 990-1000 data from controller. But I must go SQL Server with WCF only ***one time*** for 1000 rows of data (I cannot go to SQL Server all time (example 0-10,10-20,20-30)) and I put 10 data grid in view, problem is 990 rows of data in controller.

How to keep 990 rows of data in the controller ?

Comment: One option would be to use `Session`

Comment: I know session is for  little data but 990 data no little .is true or false ?

Comment: Depends how big the data is and how much memory your server has. If its a problem, serialize the collection to a file

Comment: Use [ASP.NET Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c.aspx) - that's **exactly** what it's been designed and implemented for!

Comment: very very Thanks for your answer , I will research file,caching or tempData in point of performance and security because I will should do grid for framework (one grid run dynamic  a lot of table).Do you have any idea as performance in file or caching or tempData ?

Comment: did you hear or use indexed db in html ?This able to be about me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Caching` for this

Either use the [System.Web.Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx)

Or use [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)

Depending on you setup, you might also be able to use `OutputCache`

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Result()
    {
        return Data();
    }
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs for more around this.

Comment: very very Thanks for your answer , I will research file,caching or tempData in point of performance and security because I will should do grid for framework (one grid run dynamic  a lot of table).Do you have any idea as performance in file or caching or tempData ?

Comment: Well data to the file system will require serialization and disk I/O where caching will store the data in memory, so it will be faster.  What concerns do you have regarding security?

Comment: This is grid for framework project so I cannot see data and project ,maybe it is used bank project maybe is used billing project

Answer (score -1):

your description is quite confusing. Sorry if I misunderstood your requirement.

If it involve over 1000+ of data, session is not a good option especially if your program involve other usage of session.

Since you are using MVC, you can take advantage of new option such as ViewData and TempData. You can read more about it [here](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications).

I used TempData before and it can process large amount of data (I did not count how much it was, but consider quite huge) so it should be a much better option than session.

Comment: `TempData` **IS** `Session`! And `ViewData` is for passing data from the controller to the view.

Comment: very very Thanks for your answer , I will research file,caching or tempData in point of performance and security because I will should do grid for framework (one grid run dynamic  a lot of table).Do you have any idea as performance in file or caching or tempData ?

Comment: @bgmm. `TempData` is `Session` (and it only lasts one request so woul be useless in you case). This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: Ok @Stephen Muecke I eliminate TempData

Comment: FYI, the difference between `Session` and `TempData` is TempData has `Keep()` and `Peek()`, and TempData able to store massive amount of data compare to session. I'm not sure about Peek(), but I'm currently using TempData.Keep() that keep my data in one controller and pass to another controller.